# Intellij NodeJs 6.4.0 unexpected token export

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6

I'm using Intellij Idea to create a NodeJs application in ES6.

My node.exe version is version 6.4.0

I created a simple class :

```
//wNodeClasses.js

'use strict';
export class wsUrl
 {
   constructor()
   {}
 }
```

I import the module in another file :

```
require('../../../Root/Libs/Waldata/wsNodeClasses');
```

When I start the application I always get the error :

```
d:\Dev\webDev\Root\Libs\Waldata\wsNodeClasses.js:11
export class wsUrl
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
   at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
```

- I don't use any transpiler , I want to write "pure ES6 code" (I don't want to use Babel or any equivalent)
- I understand that NodeJs 6.4.0 can interpret directly ES6 code
- Here is my Node.Exe command line :

  -max-old-space-size=8192 --expose_debug_as=v8debug

I am a newbie, I suppose I'm missing something obvious, I googled around and I didn't found an answer

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the issue.
NodeJs 6.4.0 with chrome V8 doesn't support Es6 "export" keyword or syntax.

I found a work around using

```
//Module file
module.exports=
class wsUrl
 {
 }
```

and in the consumer :

```
var wsUrl = require('../../../Root/Libs/Waldata/wsNodeClasses');
...
var MyVar = wsUrl new("test");
```

I'm still searching to have multiple classes in a same Js file (module) and export them

Comment: You can create multiple classes by assigning an object to the exports property. Example: module.exports = {class1: wsUrl, class2: AnotherClass }. Then you can access it such as: require('../../../Root/Libs/Waldata/wsNodeClasses').class1 and require('../../../Root/Libs/Waldata/wsNodeClasses').class2

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I used a different technic (I assume it's just a matter of personal preference) :

//In the module
module.exports.myClass1=class myClass1{}
module.exports.myClass2=class myClass2{}

//In the main file (consumer)
var myModule = require('../../../Root/Libs/Waldata/wsNodeClasses');
...
var test=new myModule .wsUrl("param");

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer.

I used a different technic (I assume it's just a matter of personal preference) :

```
//In the module module.exports.myClass1=class myClass1{}
module.exports.myClass2=class myClass2{} 

//In the main file (consumer) 
var myModule = require('../../../Root/Libs/Waldata/wsNodeClasses'); 
... 
var test=new myModule .wsUrl("param");
```

This works for me with NodeJs 6.4.0 and intellij (or webstorm)

PS :I'm adding an answer, because I had problems formatting my comment (could not make a "line break"